# Does JPA support mapping to sql views?

Tags: java, sql, orm, jpa, view

I'm currently using Eclipselink, but I know now days most JPA implementations have been pretty standardized. Is there a native way to map a JPA entity to a view? I am not looking to insert/update, but the question is really how to handle the @Id annotation. Every entity in the JPA world must have an ID field, but many of the views I have created do not conform to this. Is there native support for this in the JPA or do I need to use hacks to get it to work? I've searched a lot and found very little information about doing this.

Comment: Views functions as normal tables, however if you views does not fit well with JPA ORM mapping you may instead use a stored procedure to return a custom cursor formed from the view(s). You can map stored procedures in EclipseLink using the @NamedStoredProcedureQuery annotation. For more info on this Google for "EclipseLink Extensions".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While using the `@Id` annotation with fields of directly supported types is not the only way to specify an entity's identity (see `@IdClass` with multiple `@Id` annotations or `@EmbeddedId` with `@Embedded`), the JPA specification requires a primary key for each entity.

That said, you don't need entities to use JPA with database views. As mapping to a view is no different from mapping to a table from an SQL perspective, you could still use native queries (`createNativeQuery` on `EntityManager`) to retrieve scalar values instead.

Comment: JPA libs as of 10/2020 throw runtime exception "not a managed entity"

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking into this myself, and I've found a hack that I'm not 100% certain works but that looks promising.

In my case, I have a FK column in the view that can effectively function as a PK -- any given instance of that foreign object can only occur once in the view.  I defined two objects off of that one field:  one is designated the ID and represents the raw value of the field, and the other is designated read-only and represents the object being referred to.

```
@Id
@Column(name = "foreignid", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Long getForeignId() {
...

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "foreignid", insertable=false, updatable=false)
public ForeignObject getForeignObject() {
...
```

Like I said, I'm not 100% sure on this one (and I'll just delete this answer if it turns out not to work), but it got my code past a particular crash point.

Dunno if it applies to your specific situation, though.  And there's an excellent chance that after 11 months, you no longer care.  :-)  What the hell, that "Necromancer" badge doesn't just earn itself....

Answer (score 0):

In my view I have a "unique" id, so I mapped it as the Entity id.
It works very well:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="table")
@NamedQuery(name="Table.findAll", query="SELECT n FROM Table n")
public class Table implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="column_a")
    private int columnA;
```

Answer (score 0):

JPA - 2.5.4

```
    CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS needed_article as select  product_id, count(product_id) as count from product_article group by product_id;
    CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS available_article as select product_id, count(product_id) as count from article a inner join  product_article p
                                on  a.id = p.article_id and a.stock >= p.amount_of group by product_id;
    
    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX productId_available_article ON available_article (product_Id);
    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX productId_needed_article ON needed_article (product_Id);
```

Entity.java

```
@Entity
@Immutable // hibernate import
@Getter
@Setter
public class NeededArticle {
    @Id
    Integer productId;
    Integer count;
}
```

Repository.java

```
@Repository
public interface AvailableProductRepository extends CrudRepository<AvailableArticle, Integer> {

    @Query("select available.productId from AvailableArticle available, NeededArticle needed where available.productId = needed.productId and available.count = needed.count")
    List<Integer> availableProduct();
```