# How to mock DB view with Spring dbunit?

Tags: java, spring, testing, integration-testing, dbunit

I'm writing integration tests using Spring dbunit. Basically, that's fine but there's one query I need to test, but it uses a view in my db. I use `@DatabaseSetup` annotation for providing xml with test data set. But in this xml I can configure only rows for db tables, for views this doesn't work, of course. Does anybody know how to create a test row in db view and use in a test?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of choices:

1) You can create an JPA Enity and use the @Table annotation using the view name. Of course a view is read only so you will not be able to persist the entity.

2) Then to get the data into the database with dbunit:

```
i) Use an H2 in memory database and let hibernate create the database, the view will be created as a table, not a view.

ii) Use a real database and insert the data into the real tables behind the database.
```

Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16686501/jpa-and-table-views-can-it-be-done)