# Entity with a table reference to a user view

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

It is unclear how to use an entity to retrieve data from a user view.

see code below

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;
@Entity
@Table (name = "user1.view1")
```

No data is returned when performing a retrieval of data from the view.

Comment: possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16686501/jpa-and-table-views-can-it-be-done?

Comment: If you're using the entity only to read the data, you should be able to use @Table annotation to point to a view. Ultimately ORM layer will just build a select query on the underlying view. Did you enable logging to print the generated SELECT query and check if it is correct?

Comment: The period after the user name ("dw") is converted to an underscore.  The following is from the console output: 
    Hibernate:  select
        vwdimprogr0_.prgm_id as prgm_id1_0_,
        vwdimprogr0_.prgm_cd as prgm_cd2_0_,
        vwdimprogr0_.prgm_nm as prgm_nm3_0_ 
    from
        dw_vw_dim_program vwdimprogr0_