# Spring + JPA + SQL Views

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I've seen that JPA supports using views instead of tables. 
Our DBA indicated us that we need to use specific views for different kinds of stuff, for instance: One view for SELECT, another for INSERT, another for UPDATE.

Currently, I have one entity and one JPA repository related to a specific table.

My question is:
How should I handle this new views? 
Should I create one entity per view?
Is there a way to make a mapping for one entity to multiple JPA Repositories where each repository is related to a different view?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know much about `SQL views` per say, but what you are describing (`specific views for different kinds of stuff`) sound a lot like RESTful APIs. 
I can tell you we have a separate view server, and have one API for one action for each entity (update/create/select...). We use a DTO pattern for each entity to ensure separation between our service logic and repository logic.

Comment: Just for clarity, JPA doesn't have much to do with views. JPA is used to map your database structure with your service logic. Repositories are means to connect to your database, and you will probably call multiple repositories before rendering your views

Comment: @jrhee17 I have a RESTful API with DTO pattern. I also have a mapper that maps a DTO with an Entity.
The problem is that the entity is not going to be related with a table, because I have to use different views for save, update and fetch. Maybe JPA is not intended to be used in this way I really don't know.

Comment: [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69174864/410439)

Answer (score 1):

I was using Spring Boot and had the same issue. I had a view that fetches various fields from various Spring Batch tables to show status of the jobs that users run. After some experimentation the following worked:

```
@Entity
public class Job {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "JOB_INSTANCE_ID")
    private String jobInstanceId;
    @Column(name = "JOB_EXECUTION_ID")
    private String jobExecutionId;
    @Column(name = "JOB_NAME")    
    private String jobName;
    @Column(name = "JOB_TYPE")    
    private String jobType;
    @Column(name = "START_TIME")    
    private Date startTime;
    @Column(name = "END_TIME")    
    private Date endTime;
    @Column(name = "STATUS")    
    private String status;
    @Column(name = "USERNAME")    
    private String username;    

    public String getJobInstanceId() {
        return jobInstanceId;
    }

    public void setJobInstanceId(String jobInstanceId) {
        this.jobInstanceId = jobInstanceId;
    }

    public String getJobName() {
        return jobName;
    }

    public void setJobName(String jobName) {
        this.jobName = jobName;
    }   

    public Date getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    public void setStartTime(Date startTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
    }

    public Date getEndTime() {
        return endTime;
    }

    public void setEndTime(Date endTime) {
        this.endTime = endTime;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getJobType() {
        return jobType;
    }

    public void setJobType(String jobType) { 
        this.jobType = jobType; 
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getJobExecutionId() {
        return jobExecutionId;
    }

    public void setJobExecutionId(String jobExecutionId) {
        this.jobExecutionId = jobExecutionId;
    }    
}
```

And the repository definition:

```
public interface JobsRepository extends JpaRepository<Job, String> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_EXECUTION_ID, JOB_NAME, JOB_TYPE, START_TIME, END_TIME, STATUS, USERNAME  FROM JOBS_VW", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Job> getAll();
    @Query(value = "SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_EXECUTION_ID, JOB_NAME, JOB_TYPE, START_TIME, END_TIME, STATUS, USERNAME  FROM JOBS_VW WHERE JOB_INSTANCE_ID=?1", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Job> getJobsByInstanceId(String instanceId);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you will use this approach you will have JPA Entity for each view not for the table, your code won't know about how data really stored, and for each Entity you will have Repository, nothing will changed from your side.

Link to documentation about Views:
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Advanced_Topics#Views

Comment: So, Now I have:
- 1 Entity called "Test"
- 1 JPA Repository called "TestJPA"
- 1 DB table called "Test"

You are suggesting that I'll have to create one entity for each view? Something like:
- 3 views (testSelect, TestUpdate and TestInsert)
- 1 DB table called "Test" (we don't care about this)
- 3 Entitites related to the three views (TestSelect, TestUpdate, TestInsert).
- 3 JPA Repositories

Is that correct?

Comment: In theory yes, but mostly such solutions used in cases where in UI you have data that are combination of several tables and instead of complicated SQL queries you create separate view(or several views) for updating data and separate view for fetching.